# Particle in a box with absolutely continuous spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics

Let's consider a particle on a real line in a potential $V(x)$ which disappears at infinity. The Hamiltonian is:
$$
  H: W^{2,2}(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}) \\
  \big( H \, \psi \big)(x) = -\psi''(x) + V(x) \, \psi(x)
$$
(We set $\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} = 1$.) Such Hamiltonians typically have a non-empty *absolutely continuous* spectrum – therefore there are energies for which there is no corresponding eigenstate. Since physicists (except mathematical physicists) often prefer to have eigenvalues and eigenvectors, they frequently use a *finite box approximation* (eg. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.03874)): instead of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ they work on $L^2([-R, R])$ for an arbitrarily large $R$, with Dirichlet boundary conditions. Then, the corresponding Hamiltonian is:
$$
  H: \big\{ \; \psi \in W^{2,2}([-R, R]) \; \big| \; \psi(-R) = \psi(R) = 0 \; \big\} \to L^2([-R, R]) \\
  \big( H \, \psi \big)(x) = -\psi''(x) + V(x) \, \psi(x)
$$
The spectrum of this Hamiltonian is typically discrete, because the kinetic energy of a particle in a box is discrete. As pointed out in comments, instead of Dirichlet boundary conditions one can use *periodic boundary conditions* $\psi(-R) = \psi(R), \; \psi'(-R) = \psi'(R)$ to get a better approximation.

I want to know whether there are any *“physically plausible”* Hamiltonians for a **particle in a box** with either *Dirichlet* or *periodic* boundary conditions which have a **non-empty continuous spectrum**. By plausible I mean bounded from below, containing the kinetic term $P^2$ (or $(P-A)^2$ for a magnetic interaction) and a potential $V(x)$, which can be reasonably ill-behaved (eg. it may contain a point-interaction $\delta_{x_0}$).

Comment: There is a theorem of Friedrichs referred to in the introduction [here](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v162-n2-p07.pdf).

Comment: @KeithMcClary If I understand the source correctly, they give a sufficient condition for when a particle on a line has discrete spectrum. While that result is important, it's kind of the opposite of what I'm asking for – I'm interested in a condition when a particle in a box has continuous spectrum.

Comment: If imposing zero boundary conditions, as the OP suggests, one would necessarily lose some states (although such an approach is sometimes indeed used in numerical calculations.) This is why one usually uses *periodic boundary conditions*: $f(R) = f(-R)$. I think therefore that the question needs a clarification whether the author is really interested in the zero boundary conditions or whether their attack at physicists is just due to their lack of knwoledge.

Comment: @Vadim I always assumed that “particle in a box” means Dirichlet boundary condition, and periodic boundary conditions are refered to as “particle on a ring” (see eg. [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556018/42966)). I wanted to understand [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.03874.pdf) where the autors specifically mention “finite *box* approximation”. If this refers to periodic conditions, I am sorry for misunderstanding. I would like to clarify that I'm not trying to attack anybody, I genuinely want to understand the limitations of this approach.

Comment: @m93a The point that I am making is that your question needs more clarity - you could cite your paper and clarify that it is precisely zero bc that interest you. I found your comment about *non-mathematical physicists* rather amusing - math is a tool that physicists use to describe the nature and to make quantitative predictions. Being applicable to real-life situations is the ultimate test for any math used in physics - otherwise it is *just math*, however rigorous it is from the formal point of view.

Comment: @Vadim My question is about _mathematical physics_, it is even tagged so. If you think it's “just math” and not real-life physics, you have a point. If somebody on Math SE argued it's “just physics” and isn't interesting to a pure mathematician, they'd also have a point. Mathematical physics is in this middle ground between Physics SE and Maths SE. Since my question si about a technique that physicists (not matematicians) use, I am convinced it is correctly posted to Physics SE. I am also convinced that my question is well-posed as it is, if you think otherwise, please make a concrete point.

Comment: @m93a it's all fine, but you continue to ignore the mathematical substance of what I said: *particle in a box* may mean (and often means) periodic boundary conditions as well, and your question is ambiguous. I suggest that you clarify that you mean *zero boundary conditions*, and add as the context the paper that yiu cited above.

Comment: This problem is purely mathematical, because restraining the configuration space to a 1D segment is unphysical, except when the potential outside the segment is infinite. So you do not ask a question in mathematical physics, but in pure mathematics (functional analysis).

Comment: Their "V(x)→+∞ as |x|→∞" includes V(X)=∞ for large x, which is equivalent to "in a box".

Comment: @Vadim Thank you for your feedback, I've updated the question.

Comment: @DanielC One-dimensional problems are not unphysical, there are many ways in which a 3D problem reduces to a one-dimensional one. You can imagine a particle in a translationally invariant potential $V(x,y,z)=V(x)$, or a particle constrained to a [waveguide](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319185750). Or, if the three physical dimensions do not depend on each other (eg. literally a particle in a cuboid box), you can decompose the three-dimensional problem to three one-dimensional ones $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) = L^2(\mathbb{R}) \otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}) \otimes L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @DanielC Literally 1D systems are quantum wires, chains of atoms or carbon nanotubes. Then, as the previous comment notes, the problem is also true for many sitations where potential is independent on the transverse coordinates. My view is that continuous spectrom can be obtained from both zero bc and periodic bc, but in the former case it will be only "half" of the true spectrum. (*cosine* but not *sine* waves. *The box* in both cases needed for discretization.) But this is not a rigorous mathematical statement, on the level demanded by the OP.

Comment: @m93a For periodic bc the situation is very close to relation between continuous Fourier transform and the Fourier series. One uses sometimes the same trick of expanding a function known in an interval into Fourier integral - by continuing it periodicaly beyond this inerval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative for smooth bounded below potentials: *there is no continuous part of the spectrum.*

That is because, as is well known, the heat semigroup  $e^{-tH}$, $t\geq 0$, for strictly positive $t$, is made of compact, Hilbert-Schmidt, trace class operators, where $H$ is the unique selfadjoint extension of your Hamiltonian (the operator  you consider  is essentially selfadjoint with standard boundary conditions or one may always consider the Friedrichs selfadjoint extension).

*This result is more generally valid on compact manifold for operators Laplace-Beltrami + potential* (see e.g. my
[old paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002200050558) and the references therein).

As is well known, compact operators have a spectrum like this.

1. There is a  point spectrum with eigenspaces with finite dimension and at most $0$ as accumulation point of the whole spectrum.
2. The unique point of the continuous spectrum is at most $0$. Actually, it is possible to prove that, in the considered case the sequence of eigenvectors is in fact accumulated by 0. There is a general estimate by Weyl.
3. In the present case, no residual spectrum exists because the operator $e^{-tH}$ is selfadjoint.

From elementary functional calculus, it turns therefore out that the spectrum of $H$ is a pure point spectrum, made of isolated points tending to infinity, with eigenspaces with finite dimension.

I do not know what happens when using singular potentials as deltas, but I do not expect that the result changes substantially.